# Need Help Resolving Quantum ESPRESSO Calculation Error Linked to OpenMPI on Desktop

Tags: quantum-espresso, high-performance-computing, quantum-computing

I tried to run my Quantum ESPRESSO calculations as I was used to do in my desktop. But they give me an error message linked to Openmpi, and I don't know how to solve it. Can someone please help me?
The error message is:

```
[salma-Precision-3640-Tower:304573] mca_base_component_repository_open: unable to open mca_ess_singleton: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/openmpi3/mca_ess_singleton.so: invalid ELF header (ignored)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
A requested component was not found, or was unable to be opened.  This
means that this component is either not installed or is unable to be
used on your system (e.g., sometimes this means that shared libraries
that the component requires are unable to be found/loaded).  Note that
Open MPI stopped checking at the first component that it did not find.

Host:      salma-Precision-3640-Tower
Framework: ess
Component: singleton
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[salma-Precision-3640-Tower:304573] [[INVALID],INVALID] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Not found in file runtime/orte_init.c at line 247
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like orte_init failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during orte_init; some of which are due to configuration or
environment problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure;
here's some additional information (which may only be relevant to an
Open MPI developer):

  orte_ess_base_open failed
  --> Returned value Not found (-13) instead of ORTE_SUCCESS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like MPI_INIT failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during MPI_INIT; some of which are due to configuration or environment
problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure; here's some
additional information (which may only be relevant to an Open MPI
developer):

  ompi_mpi_init: ompi_rte_init failed
  --> Returned "Not found" (-13) instead of "Success" (0)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*** An error occurred in MPI_Init
*** on a NULL communicator
*** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
***    and potentially your MPI job)
[salma-Precision-3640-Tower:304573] Local abort before MPI_INIT completed completed successfully, but am not able to aggregate error messages, and not able to guarantee that all other processes were killed!
salma@salma-Precision-3640-Tower:~/Desktop/CuI2/elastic$
```

Comment: Did you use a job script to start the calculation? If yes, posting it in your question might help - the environment defined might contain some relevant insight

Comment: As mentioed by @manju9, you may include the job script or the procedure for calling mpirun. Just as a hint from the first error message, some components are not detected. Firstly double check you have mpirun installed properly on the system (mpirun --version), also check whether the library paths are correctly set in your PATH environment.

Comment: @manju9 No I didn't use any script in this calculation. I utilized just the normal command of Quantum ESPRESSO:                           `mpirun '/path/to/QE/pw.x' -in scf.in > scf.out`. I also get the same problem when I use `'/path/to/QE/pw.x'  <scf.in > scf.out`

Comment: @JaafarMehrez When I type `mpirun --version` I get this message `mpirun ( Open MPI ) 4.0.3
Report bugs to hhtp://www.open-mpi.org/community/help/`

Comment: @JaafarMehrez  Which libraries do I have to check exactly? I think I have never done that before for Open MPI, although I was using it for a whole year without any problems. I also want to mention that I'm not able to open xmgrace, even if I click on its icon or type it in the terminal, although I used to use it before without any problems. I think that maybe I deleted something from my desktop by mistake.

Comment: "I tried to run my Quantum ESPRESSO calculations as I was used to do in my desktop." So it was already installed and working, and then something changed and now it doesnt work?

Comment: @TySterling Yes exactly

Comment: Did you install anadonda? I've noticed that if you let anaconda set its path, anaconda mpi installation will become default. You can check with "which mpirun". If it's the one in anaconda, you can use use "anaconda deactivate" in your base environment. I've has this problem before!

Comment: @TySterling I have miniconda3 in my bashrc file but when I type `which mpirun` in terminal I get the following `/usr/bin/mpirun`. Can you please explain to me more what should I do?

Comment: Since it used to work and doesnt now, I suspect the configuration of some libraries or other decencies has changed but I can't say anymore without being at your computer to help or getting a lot more details. I suggest you recompile quantum espresso from scratch. Have you tried it?

Comment: @TySterling No I didn't. How do I do that from scratch only?

Comment: Delete the current installation and recompile from scratch. Follow the documentation for building quantum espresso. FYI: if you are on a debian distribution and dont need a very recent QE version built against the fastest libraries (the goal of manual compilation), just use the QE binary from the apt repo. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=quantum-espresso

Comment: @TySterling  I tried to reinstall it, but when typing `./configure` I got the following error in terminal:  `...........configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating install/make_lapack.inc
awk: error while loading shared libraries: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsigsegv.so.2: invalid ELF header
config.status: error: could not create install/make_lapack.inc`